# Convert Igrouping Anonymous type to List of string by using lambda

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have the following code with annonymous type string date, I would like to cast it to List.
Thanks

```
        var ReportDates = obj.Statuses.Where(x => x.StatusDate <= fourWeeksDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.StatusDate.ToString("dd-MMM"))
            .Select((groupDate) => new { date = groupDate.Key }).ToList();
```

Comment: found the answer
var groupDate = "";
            var ReportDates = obj.Statuses.Where(x => x.StatusDate <= fourWeeksDate)
                .GroupBy(x => x.StatusDate.ToString("dd-MMM"))
                .Select(x => groupDate = x.Key ).ToList();

need to initialized outside

Comment: If you have found the answer for your own question then please leave a post with the solution. Do not use comment section for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer

```
var groupDate = ""; 
var ReportDates = obj.Statuses.Where(x => x.StatusDate <= fourWeeksDate) 
.GroupBy(x => x.StatusDate.ToString("dd-MMM")) 
.Select(x => groupDate = x.Key )
.ToList();
```

need to initialized outside